# Hide all divs but one (Qt Webkit)

Tags: html, css, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I want to set the style of every element in my HTML document to be "display: none;", except one. I can't edit the HTML source file. I'm using Qt Webkit to try and do this, and this is my code so far:

```
QWebFrame *frame = webView->page()->mainFrame();

QWebElement document = frame->documentElement();
foreach (QWebElement element, document.findFirst("body").findAll("*"))
    element.setAttribute("style", "display: none");


QWebElement canvas = document.findFirst("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("style", "display: inline");
```

However, this hides everything, including the canvas element.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the ancestors of 'canvas' having style 'display:none;' as well an therefore not displaying anything contained within either,
My guess is that you can loop through the parents like this:

```
QWebElement parent = canvas.parent();
do{
    parent.setAttribute("style", "display: inline");
}while(parent!=null)
```

I might be a little off on the syntax though.

Comment: I tried your solution (I did edit something though: `QWebElement canvas = document.findFirst("canvas");
    QWebElement parent = canvas.parent();
    do{
        parent.setAttribute("style", "display: inline");
        parent = parent.parent();
    }while(&parent!=&body);
    canvas.setAttribute("style", "display: inline");` this is my code. However, it just gets stuck in an infinite loop (apparently &parent never equals &body).

Comment: That's because you're comparing the addresses of variables. You cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to manipulate the visibility of all `<div>` elements. To get all of them, you can substitute the following query to your `foreach` block:

```
document.findAll(QLatin1String("div")
```

The suggestion given in other answer  is also correct -- you have to make sure that a parent element of the `<canvas>` is not itself set to `display: none`.